# Errors (runaway argument & Misplaced alignment tab character &) in new tabular environment

Tags: tables, environments

I had defined the following new environment to create a numbered tabular definition table in my preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newenvironment{numdeftable}
{
\preto\tabular{\setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}}
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}
\vspace{1.5pt}
    \begin{tabular}{@{\makebox[3em][l]{\rownumber.\space}}ll}
    \end{tabular}
}
```

However, when I try and compile/build, it fails and I get the following error in my logs:

```
Runaway argument?
{ \preto \tabular {\setcounter {magicrownumbers}{0}} \newcounter {mag\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@newenv.
<inserted text> 
            \par 
l.3 \input{../../../template/common/preamble}
                                         
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.
```

and hence the place in my document where I call the environment `numdeftable` as:

```
\begin{numdeftable}
    Term1 & Definition of term 1.\\
    Term2 & Definition of term 2.\\
\end{numdeftable}
```

throws

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment numdeftable undefined.
```

Prior to trying to implement the same in an environment, I had the following in my document:

```
\preto\tabular{\setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}}
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}

\vspace{1.5pt}

\begin{tabular}{@{\makebox[3em][l]{\rownumber.\space}}ll}
    {[\texttt{Term 1}]} & Definition of term 1.\\
    {[\texttt{Term 2}]} & Definition of term 2.\\
\end{tabular}
```

which gives me the following output:

```
1. [Term 1] Definition of term 1.
2. [Term 2] Definition of term 2.
```

What could possibly be going wrong here? How can I get this fixed? Any pointers would be much helpful.

**UPDATE**

From the answers below, the error `Runaway argument?` is no longer there which means the new environment definition is working fine but I face the error `! Misplaced alignment tab character &.` when I use the environment `numdeftable` as:

```
\begin{numdeftable}
    Term1 & Definition of term 1.\\
    Term2 & Definition of term 2.\\
\end{numdeftable}
```

This is confusing. Do I need to add to/modify (clearly default tabular tab character is not working) @egreg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/587680/221792) for `numdeftable` to recognize my row format?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few weaknesses in your code.

1. You shouldn't do `\newcounter{magicrownumbers}` in the body of the definition, as it would allocate a new counter each time `numdeftable` is used.
2. `\makebox` should be `\protect`ed in the table preamble.
3. Your definition is too rigid, as it only allows for two-column tables.
4. There is no need to use `\preto`.

Reworked definition, where the table preamble has been made simpler and depending on an argument for specifying the table columns.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{numdeftable}[1]
 {% first of all reset the counter
  \setcounter{magicrownumber}{0}%
  \begin{tabular}{@{\rownumber}#1@{}}
 }
 {\end{tabular}}
\newcounter{magicrownumber}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rownumber}{%
  \makebox[3em][l]{\stepcounter{magicrownumber}\themagicrownumber.}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{numdeftable}{ll}
    Term1 & Definition of term 1.\\
    Term2 & Definition of term 2.\\
\end{numdeftable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Okay. I get it. This looks a generic piece. But I still get `! Misplaced alignment tab character &.l.58  Term1 & Definition of term 1.I can't figure out why you would want to use a tab mark here. If you just want an ampersand, the remedy is simple: Just type I\&' now. But if some right brace up above has ended a previous alignment prematurely, you're probably due for more error messages, and you might try typing S now just to see what is salvageable.` error. Any idea why?

Comment: @skrowten_hermit Sorry, but I can’t guess any reason. Please, open a new question with a minimal example of code that fails that way.

Answer (score 0):

The following should result in the expeced output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{array}

\preto\tabular{\setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}}
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}

\newenvironment{numdeftable}
{\begin{tabular}{@{\makebox[3em][l]{\rownumber.\space}}ll}}{\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{numdeftable}
    Term1 & Definition of term 1.\\
    Term2 & Definition of term 2.\\
\end{numdeftable}

\medskip

\begin{numdeftable}
    Term1 & Definition of term 1.\\
    Term2 & Definition of term 2.\\
\end{numdeftable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay. Now, the definition seems to have been fixed. But I get the error `! Misplaced alignment tab character &.l.58  Term1 & Definition of term 1.I can't figure out why you would want to use a tab mark
here. If you just want an ampersand, the remedy is
simple: Just type I\&' now. But if some right brace
up above has ended a previous alignment prematurely,
you're probably due for more error messages, and you
might try typing S now just to see what is salvageable.` This is not related to the definition of the new environment `numdeftable` right?

Comment: Do you get the quoted error message if you compile the exact code from my answer or did you incorporate it into your document?

Comment: I incorporated the changes in my document. But it’s exactly the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to tell without seing the code. How many columns do you want to use in your table? The current definition of the `numdeftable` only allows two columns. Probably you tried to use a numdeftable with more than two columns?

Comment: I want 3 columns. One with the numbering/index column, next the term column and the next with the definition column. So, that’s where things are going wrong? Before I turned to create the new environment, the above with values for each row did display 3 columns.

Comment: In the previous comment I did not count the row numbers as one column. Currently, the definition gives you one column for the row numbers and an additional two columns that you can place the actual contents of the table in.